# Pygame Init Function Broken

Tags: python, pygame

I recently discovered a bug where

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
```

gets me this error

```
pygame 2.0.1 (SDL 2.0.14, Python 3.9.2)
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  151 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  3 (X_GLXCreateContext)
  Value in failed request:  0x0
  Serial number of failed request:  90
  Current serial number in output stream:  91
```

This problem has been new and unexpected, so I think it may be just pygame not working with python 3.9.2. Does anyone know a workaround? I tried using 3.8, but nothing changed. If it matters, I am using pop os.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling pygame? Also, you can try to uninstall pygame and reinstall to a previous version, such as 2.0.0, which works on my computer.

Comment: Thanks. I tried uninstalling pygame then installing pygame 2.0.0, but it still somehow uses 2.0.1. I used "pip3 uninstall pygame", then "pip3 install pygame==2.0.0". Do you know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You should try using ```pip install -Iv pygame==2.0.0```. If that doesn't work, you can try to get an install for it online and using that link in pip, though I looked in PyPi and Sourceforge and couldn't find it there (there was a dev version, but I'm not sure that that's what you need).

Comment: I would not bother with changing the pygame version as this error is not pygame related. Seems like a problem with your graphics driver instead. The first thing I would try is restarting the X server (or simply reboot).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restarting my computer solved the issue, but I was still not able to use pygame 2.0.0.